# How to make wait some time in GWT after the Async call

Tags: gwt, gwt-rpc

In my code, I am making async call to do validation. Depeding upon return value of the validation, I need to execute some lines. 
But I am not able to put that lines in the callback method of Async = public void success(Boolean valid).

Since one of the line is super.onDrop(context) which is method of another class that can't be called inside Async callback method.

Please see the below line.  I need super.onDrop(context) will be executed after async call is completed.

`stepTypeFactory.onDropValidation(stepTypeFactory,new AsyncCallbackModal(null) {
    public void success(Boolean valid) {
        if(valid==Boolean.TRUE){
            //super.onDrop(context);
        }
    };
});`

//condition is here
super.onDrop(context);

Is there any way, i will tell gwt wait 1 or 2 seconds before super.onDrop(context) is executed.  Right now what happening is,
super.onDrop(context) is executed before the call back method is completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
stepTypeFactory.onDropValidation(stepTypeFactory,new AsyncCallbackModal(null) {
    public void success(Boolean valid) {
        if(valid==Boolean.TRUE){
            drop();
        }
    };
});

private void drop() {
   super.onDrop(context);
}
```

Comment: It is working for me.  It completely fulfilled my requirement. :)

Comment: Just wondering: couldn't you use a qualified `super`? `ContainingClass.super.onDrop(context)`

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution would be, like mentioned from Thomas Broyer in the comments:

```
stepTypeFactory.onDropValidation(stepTypeFactory,new  AsyncCallbackModal(null) {
    public void success(Boolean valid) {
       if(valid==Boolean.TRUE){
       ContainingClass.super.onDrop(context);
       }
   };
});
```

Eclipse does not suggests this solution when using the code completion, but it works.

Also i would possibly reconsider your design, because it can get very tricky (by experience) when you have many Callbacks which are connecting/coupling classes. But this is just a quick thought, i neither know the size of your project nor the design.